# jQuery Star Rating plugin - select in callback causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Using the [jQuery Star Rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-API) everything works well until I select a star rating from the rating's callback handler. Simple example:

```
$('.rating').rating({
    ...

    callback: function(value){ 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ...
            data: {rating: value},
            success: function(data){
                $('.rating').rating('select', 1);
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

I'm guessing this infinite loop occurs because the callback is fired after a manual 'select' as well. Once a user submits their rating I'd like to 'select' the average rating across all users (this value is in data returned to the success handler).

How can I do this without triggering an infinite loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have terrible documentation.

Digging through the source code, you will find that the "select" function takes an additional parameter `wantCallBack`. So set that to false:

```
$('.rating').rating('select', 1, false);
```